# How to build a nodejs app with typescript and ESmodules without webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-modules, tsc

I have a nodejs app, that is meant to run locally in my mac, not in a browser. I want to use typescript, compile it, and run the script.

Here is the code:

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && yarn tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.5.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pdf2json": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

I just want to import a service. In TS, the extension is not needed.

```
// index.ts

import { IdentifyFileUseCase } from './application/use-cases/IdentifyFile.useCase';

const identifyFileUseCase = new IdentifyFileUseCase()
identifyFileUseCase.execute()
```

when running

```
yarn build
```

I get in the `dist/index.js`

```
import { IdentifyFileUseCase } from './application/use-cases/IdentifyFile.useCase';
const identifyFileUseCase = new IdentifyFileUseCase();
identifyFileUseCase.execute();
```

since I told to be this ESmodules,

```
from './application/use-cases/IdentifyFile.useCase';
```

this path in the `dist/index.js` is wrong because `.js` extension is mandatory and my script crashes when running

```
node dist/index.js
```

This is the error:

```
node dist/index.js
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/albert.montolioagua/Documents/coding_area/personal/ts-pdf-reader/dist/application/use-cases/IdentifyFile.useCase' imported from /Users/albert.montolioagua/Documents/coding_area/personal/ts-pdf-reader/dist/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:916:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

How can I make TS to compile ts into js with the right extension in the path?

I need webpack or can I avoid it?

is my tsconfig.json ok?

Comment: Type the path in the original TS file correctly: `import { IdentifyFileUseCase } from './application/use-cases/IdentifyFile.useCase.js';`